# FileNotFoundException when trying to email an image with JavaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a simple program to send an email containing an image. The image and java file are directly in the same folder.
[image: file dir]

When running the program I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: spotify.jpeg (The system cannot find the file specified)`. error.

```
// This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
                    "spotify.jpeg");

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

            // add image to the multipart
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Assuming that you are using a maven project structure, non-source-files like your `.jpeg` need to be in `/src/main/resources`, not `/src/main/java`.

Comment: Files stored within the "source" context won't be accessible as "files" when executed.  You should be using `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on your needs

Comment: You can also use [`URLDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/URLDataSource.html) instead of `FileDataSource`

Comment: Once i've moved my `.jpeg` to resources how should i reference it? `../spotify.jpeg`? Can you elaborate further on the `Class#getResource` @MadProgrammer

Comment: `new URLDataSource(getClass().getResource("/spotify.jpeg"))`

Comment: Oh ok that works but it seems to send it as an attached file. I'm trying to send it as like the embedded images in promo emails you get